# js + lodash js debound + php: debound function lodash is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, lodash

i have a input where onkeyup function i wanna do a debound, but lodash isn working for that, someone can check if im doing something wrong? this is the input

```js
    function autocomplete_usuario_debounced(){
    
    
        _.debounce(autocomplete_usuario,500);
    
     } 
    
    function autocomplete_usuario(ev) {
        $("#modal-search").css("height","500px");
        if (0 < document.getElementById("buscadora").value.length) {
            document.getElementById("auto_usuario").style.visibility = "visible";
            var a = {
                busqueda: document.getElementById("buscadora").value
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST"
                , url: base_url + "/*********/********/"
                , cache: !1
                , data: a
                , success: function (response) { 
                 response = JSON.parse(response);
                 if(response['success']){
                  auto_usuario.innerHTML = response['mensaje'];
                 }
                 else{
                     Materialize.toast('I am a toast', 2000,'',function(){ window.location.replace("/login");})
                 }
                }
            })
        }
        else{
         document.getElementById("auto_usuario").style.visibility = "hidden", auto_usuario.innerHTML = "";
         $("#modal-search").css("height","unset");
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="buscadora" autofocus <?php if ($this->uri->segment(1) != null): ?> readonly <?php endif ?> class="input_box" name="tel_or_ced" onkeyup="autocomplete_usuario_debounced();">
```

when i put the autocomplete_usuario in the onkeyup in the input works fine but when i put autocomplete_usuario_debounced is not working

sorry for my bad english :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the `autocomplete_usuario_debounced` function this way:

```
window.autocomplete_usuario_debounced = _.debounce(autocomplete_usuario,500);
```